# Why there no 'mysql' database?

Tags: mysql

I installed mysql by brew.

When I use

```
mysql -u root

mysql > show databases;
```

it shows

```
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
+--------------------+
```

Why is there no `mysql` database?

Comment: You haven't used a password, so it is possible that you actually connected as an anonymous user. Use SELECT CURRENT_USER(); to verify that you are connected as a root@localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Issues seems related to mysql distribution package. Although, you recreate the mysql database with command:

```
mysql_install_db
```

[Mysql Documentation here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-install-db.html)